# accepts_nested_attributes_for when using class_name on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Here's the code:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # So we can reference the user's Client information with user.as_client
    has_one :as_client, :class_name => 'ClientAccount'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :as_client
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>

<%= f.fields_for :as_client do |c| %>
  <%= c.label :website %>
  <%= c.text_field :website %>
<%= end %>
```

Now, when I submit the form, this is what gets sent:

```
{"user"=>{"first_name"=>"Name", "as_client_attributes"=> "website"=>"http://website.com"}}, "commit"=>"Update User"}
```

And I get this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: as_client_attributes
```

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `attr_accessible :as_client_attributes` in the User model so you can mass-assign attributes via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I had read your answer wrong at first, I did your solution backwards. I noticed that and fixed it, it's good to go now. I can't believe it was staring me in the face! Thanks!